# Finding a specific byte in a file

Tags: c, file, char

I have a file in which I'm trying to look for this sequence of bytes: 0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, and 0xE0. For right now, let's assume I'm only looking for 0xFF. I made this program for testing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void analyzeFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* filePtr = fopen(filename, "rb");

    int numImages = 0;

    while (!feof(filePtr))
    {
        char bytes;

        bytes = getc(filePtr);

        printf("%c", bytes);

        if ((bytes == 0xFF))
        {
            numImages++;
            printf("image found!\n");
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", numImages);
}
```

This isn't working. When I call analyzeFile with parameter "test.txt", it prints the contents of the file out fine, but doesn't detect a single 0xFF byte:

contents of test.txt:

```
aÿØÿÿà1234
```

output:

```
aÿØÿÿà1234
0
```

for reference, 0xFF is equivalent to y-diaeresis, ÿ, according to ASCII.

Comment: `0xFF` is not defined by ASCII. Use `hexdump` or some other hex viewer to see the actual bytes in numerical form

Comment: Also change your type to *unsigned char*, otherwise your comparison won't work (see this funny experiment: https://ideone.com/Pk0rGg). That is because during the comparison and integer promotion the signed `char` value will get "sign-extended" to `0xFFFFFFFF` and compared to `0x000000FF`

Comment: try `char bytes` -> `int bytes`

Comment: `while (!feof(filePtr))` is a bug. `feof` returns whether an earlier read found EOF. Just call `getc` and check whether it returns `EOF`.

Comment: Why not pass it a JPEG (JFIF) file instead of assuming that a text file is encoded like you think it is?

Comment: I changed it to unsigned char, but now it's only detecting one of the y-diaereses, and outputting

`aÿØÿÿà1234
image found!
1`

I need it to be able to find multiple characters.

Comment: @humanbean Most likely it is detecting `EOF`. Change to `int` as was suggested above. And get rid of `while (!feof(filePtr))` - see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You're not looking for "y-diaereses", whatever that means, You're looking for FF bytes. and the one you do find is probably the `EOF` being misinterpreted as FF. Using an `unsigned char` is wrong. You need an `int`. Please refer to my earlier comment.

Comment: I changed `unsigned char bytes` to `int bytes`; same output as when it was just `char bytes`.

Comment: @humanbean Meaning that your file does not contain 0xFF bytes.

Comment: Your comments helped a lot, as well as the posted answer Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. For the first, see: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/10871073)

The second problem is that [`getc` (or `fgetc`) returns an `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc), not a `char`. As it stands, your `char` value of `0xFF` is sign-extended (to `0xFFFFFFFF`, most likely) when it is promoted to an `int` for the `if ((bytes == 0xFF))` comparison. So, use `int` for your `bytes` variable and change the loop to test the value that was read for the `EOF` signal:

```c
void analyzeFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* filePtr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!filePtr) { // Add some error handling...
        printf("Could not open file!");
        return;
    }
    int numImages = 0;
    int bytes;
    while ( ( bytes = getc(filePtr) ) != EOF) {
        printf("%02X %c\n", (unsigned)bytes, bytes);

        if (bytes == 0xFF) { // Removed redundant extra parentheses
            numImages++;
            printf("image found!\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(filePtr); // Don't forget to close the file!
    printf("%d\n", numImages);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but isn't the  cast `(char)bytes` as a parameter to `printf` useless? It will get casted back to `int`  by the default promotions.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: The value of `(char)bytes` is implementation defined if `bytes > CHAR_MAX` (which can only happen if `char` is a signed type), so probably better not to cast it to `char`. Also, `%X` expects an `unsigned int`, so you *do* need a cast (to `unsigned int`) for that one.

Comment: @IanAbbott Fair comment - see edit.